# Mocking a Chain of Calls Across Libraries

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the [hammock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hammock/0.2.3) library to abstract requests to an internal API. In my code, wherein `self.api` is a Hammock object, I make the following call:

posts = self.api.posts().GET(params=params).json().get('objects')

where .GET returns a response object, .json converts it to a dictionary, and .get returns the value for the 'objects' key in that dictionary.

What I want is for that whole call to simply return a fixture I have already set up. When I try something like `self.worker.api.posts.get = Mock(return_value=fixture)`, however, it doesn't work. It calls out to the actual API.

Is this possible, or should I give up on attempting to mock such a specific call and just settle for mocking the method that contains it?

Comment: Mocking the method that contains this whole thing would be cleaner without any doubts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set all `return_values` on mocks. When you call `self.api.posts()` a mock is returned and you want to get this mock and set it's return value, which will be an object that has a `GET()` method which you also want to mock it's return value until the last call you want to mock.

Here's the example:

`self.api.posts.return_value.GET.return_value.json.return_value.get = Mock(return_value=fixture)`

My working example:

`json_obj = mock.MagicMock(return_value=self.hardcoced_labels)
con.return_value.repos.return_value.labels.GET.return_value.json = json_obj`